# unable to extract and separately colour subunits in d3

Tags: d3.js

I've been following the "[Let’s Make a Map](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)" tutorial, but trying to combine it with [a different one- from another country](https://milkator.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/making-a-map-of-germany-with-topojson/)- to see if I really understand what's going on- not just blindly entering commands like a trained monkey.

I've gotten to the part about subunit colouring, and hit a wall.

My code looks like this- it's pretty minimal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>


</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 1160;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([10.5, 51.35])
    .scale(3000)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


d3.json("de.json", function(error, de) {


    var test = topojson.feature(de, de.objects.subunits);


    console.log(test);


  svg.selectAll(".subunit")
     // .data(subunits.features)
     .data(topojson.feature(de, de.objects.subunits).features)
     .enter().append("path")
     .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
     .attr("d", path);
});



</script>
```

I thought I should be able to colour it like below in the CSS section but it doesn't work!:

```
.subunit{fill:#fff;}
.subunit.Nordrhein-Westfalen{ fill: #aba; }
.subunit.Baden-Württemberg{ fill: #bab; }
.subunit.Hessen{ fill: #bcb; }
.subunit.Niedersachsen{ fill: #cbc; }
.subunit.Thüringen{ fill: #cdc; }
.subunit.Hamburg{ fill: #dcd; }
.subunit.Schleswig-Holstein{ fill: #ded; }
.subunit.Rheinland-Pfalz{ fill: #ede; }
.subunit.Saarland{ fill: #efe; }
.subunit.Sachsen-Anhalt{ fill: #fef; }
.subunit.Brandenburg{ fill: #aaa; }
.subunit.Mecklenburg-Vorpommern{ fill: #bbb; }
.subunit.Bayern { fill: #ccc; }
.subunit.Sachsen { fill: #ddd; }
.subunit.Bremen { fill: #eee; }
.subunit.Berlin { fill: #fff; }
```

So lately I've been trying to log the data to the console but I can't figure out how to do that either- all I see are the methods that are applicable to the data object.

*How can I separately colour all the subunits, viz. states?*

Here is a small sample of my json data:

```
    {"type":"Topology","objects":{"subunits":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"NAME":"Nordrhein-Westfalen","name":"Nordrhein-Westfalen"},"arcs":[[0,1,2,3]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"NAME":"Baden-Württemberg","name":"Baden-Württemberg"},"arcs":[[4,5,6,7]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"NAME":"Hessen","name":"Hessen"},"arcs":[[8,9,-7,10,-1,11]]},{"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"NAME":"Bremen","name":"Bremen"},"arcs":[[[12]],[[13,14]]]},{"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"NAME":"Niedersachsen","name":"Niedersachsen"},"arcs":[[[15]],[[16]],[[17]],[[18]],[[19]],[[20]],[[21]],[[22]],[[23]],[[24,25,26,27,28,29,-12,-4,30,-15,31],[-13]]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"NAME":"Thüringen","name":"Thüringen"},"arcs":[[32,33,-9,-30,34]]},{"type":"Polygon","properties":{"NAME":"Hamburg","name":"Hamburg"},"arcs":[[-25,35,36]]},{"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"NAME":"Schleswig-Holstein","name":"Schleswig-Holstein"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.attr("class",` function, your datum has no property of `id`.  Inspecting it, the property you are looking for is `d.properties.name`, so:

```
.attr("class", function(d) {return "subunit " + d.properties.name; })
```

---

Full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qzzOXbYmnMgLNcSRqlXY?p=preview).

Comment: great find- thank you. now I'm working on the`svg.selectAll(".place-label")` method- and I'm exactly using `.text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });` but now the output of *this one* is undefined- how is this possible?! :/ 

This part is from the `#Displaying Places` component of the "Let’s Make a Map" tutorial

Comment: @s.matthew.english, that works for me, see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/qzzOXbYmnMgLNcSRqlXY?p=preview)