# inexplicable inability to render city name labels on a d3.js map: out of scope NAME?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm following the canonical "[Let’s Make a Map](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/)" tutorial- but to spice things up I'm melding it with [one about Germany](https://milkator.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/making-a-map-of-germany-with-topojson/)- so I'm working with slightly different data.

Things are so far working out- [barring this minor hiccup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37776407/unable-to-extract-and-separately-colour-subunits-in-d3)- but now I've come to the section "#Displaying Places" which is where you're supposed to show the names of the cities on the map.

The problem is happening in the following line:

```
   .text(function(d) {
        if (d.properties.name!=="Berlin" &&
            d.properties.name!=="Bremen"){

                //for some reason this is undefined
                console.log(d.properties.name);
                return d.properties.name;
        }
    })
```

The value of that `console.log(d.properties.name);` is always undefined and I can't figure out why!

I suppose it's because `name` is out of scope for `d`- but I don't know how to fix it. **Is that right? If so- how to fix it? if not- what is the real problem?**

Here is what my code looks like- it's pretty concise:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.subunit{fill:#fff;}
.subunit.Nordrhein-Westfalen{ fill: #aba; }
.subunit.Baden-Württemberg{ fill: #bab; }
.subunit.Hessen{ fill: #bcb; }
.subunit.Niedersachsen{ fill: #cbc; }
.subunit.Thüringen{ fill: #cdc; }
.subunit.Hamburg{ fill: #dcd; }
.subunit.Schleswig-Holstein{ fill: #ded; }
.subunit.Rheinland-Pfalz{ fill: #ede; }
.subunit.Saarland{ fill: #efe; }
.subunit.Sachsen-Anhalt{ fill: #fef; }
.subunit.Brandenburg{ fill: #aaa; }
.subunit.Mecklenburg-Vorpommern{ fill: #bbb; }
.subunit.Bayern { fill: #ccc; }
.subunit.Sachsen { fill: #ddd; }
.subunit.Bremen { fill: #eee; }
.subunit.Berlin { fill: #fff; }

.subunit-boundary {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #777;
  stroke-dasharray: 2,2;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}


.place,
.place-label {
  fill: #444;
  font-size:14px;
}

text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
}


</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 1160;

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
    .center([10.5, 51.35])
    .scale(3000)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

var path = d3.geo.path()
    .projection(projection);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);


d3.json("de.json", function(error, de) {

    //colouring the different subunits
    svg.selectAll(".subunit")
       .data(topojson.feature(de, de.objects.subunits).features)
       .enter().append("path")
       .attr("class", function(d) {
        // console.log(d.properties.name);
        return "subunit " + d.properties.name;
       })
       .attr("d", path);

    //adding a border to the states
    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(de, de.objects.subunits, function(a,b) {
            if (a!==b ||
                a.properties.name === "Berlin"||
                a.properties.name === "Bremen"){
                    var ret = a;
                }
                    return ret;
                }))
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "subunit-boundary");

    // add small black dots for populated places
    svg.append("path")
       .datum(topojson.feature(de, de.objects.places))
       .attr("d", path)
       .attr("class", "place");



    //trying to display names of cities
    svg.selectAll(".place-label")
       .data(topojson.feature(de, de.objects.places).features)
       .enter().append("text")
       .attr("class", "place-label")
       .attr("transform", function(d) {

            //small test
            //console.log( "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")" );

            return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")";
        })
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .text(function(d) {
            if (d.properties.name!=="Berlin" &&
                d.properties.name!=="Bremen"){

                    //for some reason this is undefined
                    console.log(d.properties.name);
                    return d.properties.name;
            }
        })
       .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6;
        })
       .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
            return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? "start" : "end";
       });



});

</script>
```

[Here is the data file](https://github.com/s-matthew-english/functional-octo-chainsaw/blob/master/de.json).

**EDIT**

*expected*

[image]

*actual*

[image]

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37635547/interactive-graph-of-europe-using-d3/37644652

Comment: @Klaujesi that wasn't really very helpful- the answer to that question is long and seems very general- is there a specific part that you think I should look at?

Comment: You has no name on your topojson 'places' just the coordinate of the point. topojson.feature(de, de.objects.places).features <- don't give you a .name just the coordinate of the point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your .topojson you have two section:

- properties: names of your counties and polygons
- places: coordinates of the points

You access the first collection with:

```
de.objects.subunits
```

And the second collection through:

```
de.subunits.places
```

After file is loaded sepearte into two different variables to use it:

```
d3.json("de.json", function(error, de) {
    var counti = topojson.feature(de, de.objects.subunits)
    var places = topojson.feature(de, de.objects.places)
```

then referenciate the content adding .features

```
   .data(counti.features)   // <-- to draw your paths and get the .name: München
```

**or**

```
   .data(places.features)  // <-- to draw the circles for the cities: "coordinates": [11.573039376427117, 48.131688134368815]
```

Mike's topojson has:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Ayr"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      -4.617021378468872,
      55.44930882146421
    ]
  }
```

and you has:

```
 {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {},
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      11.573039376427117,
      48.131688134368815
    ]
  }
```

Mike's point properties looks like this:

[image]

and point coordinates

[image]

Your point properties:

[image]

Solution:

**The right way**

- Open your map on GIS software (ArcGIS-pay, Q-GIS-free) edit and correct paths and points properties and export as TopoJSON again.-

**Easy way**

- Go to: [geojson.io](http://geojson.io) load your json and add propertie name to your point (16 points, easy cake) and save as TopoJSON again.-

[image]

Now you're there correct countie info deleting one column (you has duplicate info)

[image]

Comment: I still don't understand how to apply this insight to the function labelled `//trying to display names of cities`, should I change the line `return d.properties.name;`?

Comment: what do you think about [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785089/binding-d3-elements-to-json-objects-lost-in-space)

Comment: ah! I just undeleted it :)

Comment: Did you get your map?

Comment: not really- all the labels are wrong- anyway- I'm not just trying to get a map- I'm trying to get the knowledge of why this mess is happening and how to fix it

Comment: Your data has wrong structure. Correct your initial data and the rest will go easy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114535/discussion-between-klaujesi-and-s-matthew-english).

Answer (score 1):

@Klaujesi has explained the reason pretty well.

I am just going to solve the issue by a work around.

Since there is no property inside the Feature, so you can get the property from `de.objects.subunits`, like below.

```
.text(function(d, i) {
//here i is the index of the place.
//de.objects.subunits.geometries[i].properties will give you the name that you are looking for.
            d.properties = de.objects.subunits.geometries[i].properties;
            if (d.properties.name!=="Berlin" &&
                d.properties.name!=="Bremen"){

                    //for some reason this is undefined
                    console.log(d);
                    return d.properties.name;
            }
        })
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IBD0Elo9eyZbj9dShZyt?p=preview)

Comment: hmm- so then- you just changed the meaning of what that `d` represents? this is a clever solution certainly- but I the names of the states are actually incorrect for some reason- they display- but not in the right place

Comment: the names of the cities are associated with `Polygon` as opposed to the states which are associated with `MultiPolygon`, right now the names of states are appearing near the circle which represents the capital cities in a kind of random way

Comment: Not really d.properties was blank i just set its value from `de.objects.subunits` the reason is that properties inside the feature is blank. May be you can put a screen shot of what you are expecting i don't see any thing coming up randomly.